# How would you implement this function in CUDA? (offsets in sorted integer vector)

Tags: algorithm, cuda, thrust

I have a sorted integer array on the device, e.g.:

```
[0,0,0,1,1,2,2]
```

And I want the offsets to each element in another array:

```
[0,3,5]
```

(since the first 0 is at position 0, the first 1 at position 3 and so on)
I know how many different elements there will be beforehand. How would you implement this efficiently in CUDA? I'm not asking for code, but a high level description of the algorithm you would implement to compute this transformation. I already hat a look at the various functions in the thrust name space, but could not think of any combination of thrust functions to achieve this. Also, does this transformation have a widely accepted name?

Comment: Are the offset stored in the integer position the represent? in example: [0,0,0,2,2,3,3] -> [0,x,3,5], with 'x' as a null value.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand you correctly. There should not be any null values in the output. However, null values could be easily removed using thrust::remove_if()...

Comment: you could ask here: http://encode.ru/forums/2-Data-Compression

Comment: You might do `atomicMin(&result[input[index]], index)` for every index (result must be initialized to high values). But performance won't be very good.

Comment: Thanks for the input harold, but performance is rather critical in my application.

Comment: You should be able to do this one with ```thrust::unique_by_key``` plus ```thrust::counting_iterator```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this in Thrust using `thrust::unique_by_key_copy` with `thrust::counting_iterator`.  The idea is to treat your integer array as the `keys` argument to `unique_by_key_copy` and to use a sequence of ascending integers (i.e., `counting_iterator`) as the `values`.  `unique_by_key_copy` will compact the values array into the indices of each unique `key`:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/unique.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  thrust::device_vector<int> keys(7);
  keys[0] = 0; keys[1] = 0; keys[2] = 0;
  keys[3] = 1; keys[4] = 1; keys[5] = 2; keys[6] = 2;

  std::cout << "keys before unique_by_key_copy: [ ";
  thrust::copy(keys.begin(), keys.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
  std::cout << "]" << std::endl;

  thrust::device_vector<int> offsets(3);

  thrust::unique_by_key_copy(keys.begin(), keys.end(),          // keys
                             thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), // [0, 1, 2, 3, ...] are the values
                             thrust::make_discard_iterator(),   // discard the compacted keys
                             offsets.begin());                  // the offsets are the values

  std::cout << "offsets after unique_by_key_copy: [ ";
  thrust::copy(offsets.begin(), offsets.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
  std::cout << "]" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
$ nvcc test.cu -run
keys before unique_by_key_copy: [ 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 ]
offsets after unique_by_key_copy: [ 0 3 5 ]
```

Comment: Nice, I hadn't noticed there was such thing as a discard iterator!

Comment: @Jared How could you solve the problem for an unknown number of offset?

Comment: @pQB Great question. You could give ```unique_by_key_copy``` ```discard_iterator```s for both output sequences and then use the returned iterator to compute the result's size. Now you can run the algorithm again with a properly-sized output buffer. This strategy should be general enough to use with any of the algorithms which produce input-dependent output. Of course, exploiting domain-specific knowledge about the input would probably yield a more efficient solution. Not sure what you could do about this particular problem, but i bet scan would be involved :)

Comment: Actually, it's just a reduction. What you'd do is ```zip(keys.begin(), keys.begin()+1)```, which will pair each key with its neighbor to the right. The idea is to look for the beginning of runs of keys in the input, which will occur when the two keys do not match. Now all you need to do is count the number of times a key does not match its neighbor.

Answer (score 4):

Although I've never used thrust library, what about this possible approach (simple but maybe effective):

```
int input[N];  // your sorted array
int offset[N]; // the offset of the first values of each elements. Initialized with -1

// each thread will check an index position
if (input[id] > input[id-1]) // bingo! here begins a new value
{
    int oid = input[id];  // use the integer value as index
    offset[oid] = id;     // mark the offset with the beginning of the new value
}
```

In your example the output will be:

```
[0,3,5]
```

But if the input array is:

```
[0,0,0,2,2,4,4]
```

Then the output will be:

```
[0,-1, 3, -1, 5]
```

Now, if thrust can do it for you, remove_if( offset[i] == -1 ) and compact the array.

This approach will waste lot of memory for the offset array, but as you dont know how many offset you are going to find, the worst case will use as much memory as the input array.

On the other hand, the few instruction per thread compared to the global memory load will limit this implementation by memory bandwidth. There are some optimization for this case as process some values per thread.

My 2 cents!

Answer (score 1):

Scan is the algorithm you're looking for.  If you don't have an implementation lying around, the Thrust library would be a good resource.  (Look for thrust::scan)

Scan (or "parallel prefix sum") takes an input array and generates an output where each element is the sum of the inputs to that point: [1 5 3 7] => [1 6 9 16]

If you scan predicates (0 or 1 depending on an evaluated condition) where the predicate checks whether a given element the same as the preceding element, then you compute the output index of the element in question.  Your example array

[0 0 0 1 1 2 2]
[0 0 0 1 0 1 0] <= predicates
[0 0 0 1 1 2 2] <= scanned predicates

Now you can use the scanned predicates as indices to write your output.

Comment: Maybe I'm slow off the mark here, but how can I use the scanned predicates to write my output?

Comment: The scanned predicate gives the output index.

Answer (score 0):

Good question and the answer depends on what you need to do with it after. Let me explain.

As soon as this problem can be solved in O(n) (where n is the input length) on CPU, you will suffer from memory allocation and copying (Host -> Device (input) and Device -> Host (result)) drawbacks. This will leads to performance degradation against simple CPU solution.

*Even if your array already in device memory, each computation block need to read it to local or registers (at least access device memory), and it can't be done significantly faster than on CPU.*

In general CUDA accelerate perfomance well if:

1. Asymptotic complexity of computations is high comparing to input data length. For example input data length is n and complexity is O(n^2) or O(n^3).
2. There is way to split task to independed or weak depended subtasks.

So if I was you, I would not try to do computations of such kind on CUDA if it's possible. And if it must be some standalone function or output format convertion for some other function I would do in CPU.

If it's part of some more complex algorithm the answer is more complicated. If I was on your place I would try to somehow change `[0,3,5]` format, because it adds limitations for utilization CUDA computation power. You can't effectively split your task on independed blocks. Just for example if I process 10 integers in one computation thread and next 10 integers in other. The second one don't know where to place his outputs until first one not finished. May be I will split an array on subarrays and store answer for each subarray separately. It's highly depends on what computations you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The sorted integer array is rather large, up to 4M elements, and I need the result of the transformation on the device again, which would typically be about 100k integers in size. I expect that copying these arrays from the device and back would be rather costly.
As for your remarks concerning the complexity: There are efficient algorithms computing a histogram on the GPU, which is also in O(n). I think histogram computation and my problem rather similiar, maybe there's an idea there...

Comment: Histogram computation will be effective if memory already on device and will be needed in device again. But in contrast to your case histogram doesn't suffer from format. I think changing format or separate storing is the key.

Comment: WW's 'answer' falls far from the mark.  A linear-time and work-efficient parallel algorithm is eminently doable.

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware for simple linear-time task like this one, if data not in device memory (that what I've talking about), you have no chance to beat good CPU implementation with CUDA. Give me your code and I will challenge it.

Comment: WW, you might infer from the title "How would you implement this function in CUDA?" that the poster would like to hear something other than that they could just as well do the task on the CPU.  For data already in CUDA device memory, CUDA will destroy any CPU implementation for this task - as has already been said, the transfer overhead would overwhelm whatever performance advantage the CPU has. Thrust can perform scan at >5 billion integers per second.  A competitive CPU implementation would have to be both multithreaded and SSE2-optimized; CUDA would look good in a side-by-side comparison.

Comment: 1. Seems you miss the second part of my answer. I suggested to change output format if data is already in device and will be needed after. 2. You forget that CUDA devices have almost the same RAM (a little faster) as CPU. And you need to access it to do computations.  And in general it doesn't give you the same level of parallelism as computation units.
3. I bet SSE optimization will be enough for competitive implementation (for nearest price level hardware).
4. Food for thought: BLAS level one contains a lot of vector O(n) operations, but you will never see it in cublas benchmarks, guess why?